# When should I write my own random number algorithm instead of using a stock math function?

Tags: algorithm, random, lua

So I am taking a scripting test in Lua, and I am given this question:

1. Create an algorithm to generate a deck of cards, 1-52. Shuffle the deck of cards (do not use something like array.randomize() ). Then hand out 5 cards to two different players. Being that each card must be dealt to a different player at a time.

Typically I would do something like this to get a random number

```
local newDeck = {} --assume this array has all 52 cards in a playing deck
math.randomseed( os.time() )
local card = math.random(#newDeck)
```

...but it seems that the question is specifically asking that I do NOT use a stock math function.

*(do not use something like array.randomize())*

What would be the advantage to that? I can't imagine that the player of such a game would even notice a difference between random and pseudo random.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in the last part since computers can't really create anything that is not pseudorandom in some sense. It's actually debatable whether humans can or not either (it goes into the whole fate/destiny thing...deep stuff).

Comment: This question sounds like you should use the stock random function, but not the shuffling part. The point of this is for you to learn how to shuffle an array (hint: Fisher-Yates)

Comment: For a more practical answer: The PRNG included with most standard libraries sucks. So whenever you need high quality randomness, you need to swap it for a decent implementation. For an online game you need to even use a cryptographic PRNG, since else players might cheat.

Comment: @ShashankGupta - You are right. That was poorly phrased. It is all pseudo random. I should have said the difference between a custom randomization algorithm and a lua library randomizer.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Good to know. I didn't even realize there was such a thing as a cryptographic PRNG, I will try out the Fisher-Yates.

Answer (score 3):

If only it were that simple. Most random number generators that are part of a language are *linear congruential generators*, meaning that the next term `J`, say, is related to the previous one `I` by

```
J = (aI + b) mod c
```

Where `a`, `b`, `c` are constants.

**This means that it is possible to decipher the sequence from a single digit number of terms!** (It's a set of simultaneous equations with bit of trickery to handle the modulus).

I'd say that an astute player is *bound* to notice the pseudo random nature of your sequence and may even *game* the system by unpicking your generator. You need to use a more sophisticated scheme. (Early attempts include Park-Miller and Bays-Durham; fairly well-known approaches).

Comment: ..but if my randomseed was based off the system clock, wouldn't the player have to keep one eye on the clock and notice a connection between the current time and 1 0f 52 cards to notice that it was pseudo? I still can't imagine that happening.

Comment: @PHazer It is possible. There are people that hack the Nintendo DS clocks for Pokemon games to abuse the RNG to get shiny pokemon (they have a very rare chance of appearing but there have been programs made to calculate seeds and predict future numbers from the generator). These programs work based on a user-inputted time, the time you start up your Pokemon game. It really just depends on how dedicated someone would be to RNG abuse your game.

Comment: @ShashankGupta True, but the NDS clocks only seed to second-accuracy, not millisecond. I'm not saying it's impossible, just saying that Nintendo screwed up their implementation to make it *much* more abusable than it should be.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are welcome to use the built in random number generator to get random numbers, but prohibited from using any built in array shufflers that may exist. How can you use a rng to have each card equally likely to be in each position?

Answer (score 0):

you could just write something that draws a random card and puts it in the shuffled deck:

```
function shuf(tab)
    local new = {}
    for k=1,#tab do
        new[#new+1]=table.remove(tab,math.random(#tab))
    end
end
```

This approach makes sure you have no doubles.

I don't really think using a different RNG would matter that much unless you're doing cryptography, or something else that really matters.

Interpreting the question: just don't use a library function written for doing this. But there is a difference between a shuffler and a random number generator, since the latter can return double values while the former can't.